# How does intelligence differ from predictive ability?

Tags: intelligence

Is intelligence merely a predictive tool?

We conceptualize situations using a predictive-based statistical framework since every fact/factor cannot be accounted for. This framework is reinforced when output produces unintended consequences. This framework also has a biological basis and this basis determines the extent that which the framework is able to operate, e.g., we evolve sight to provide the ability to characterize objects (biological), but how intricate we see is bounded by biology. Better frameworks are therefore capable of dealing with and traversing more effectively in the world. The framework also deals with the accuracy-efficiency tradeoff - attempting to account for an overwhelming amount of variables in a given scenario will create mental fatigue, thus decreasing the efficiency of responding to further novel situations.

Comment: There's an interesting and peripherally related read: [dragonfly hunting-behaviour and predictive models](https://journals.biologists.com/jeb/article/218/9/1278/14533/Dragonfly-hunting-is-based-on-predictive-models) since you express interest in biology.